# Colleagues and I forced to use different SQL Server date formats

Tags: sql-server, date, date-format

This is really starting to bug me now, if anyone has ever come across it. We don't have a full fledged DBA here and we can't find a setting that would fix the issue.

Basically, when running queries, each of us has to set the DATEFORMAT differently. My colleague to the left has to SET DATEFORMAT DMY whereas if I pick up any queries she's written I have to actually force the query into SET DATEFORMAT YMD. My other colleague ends up having to do SET DATEFORMAT YDM like the US format.

Is this something that can be changed with a setting somewhere? Of all the workplaces I've used MS SQL Serve I've never come across this before and have no idea how to fix it!

EDIT: In response to comments; yes, these queries will be run on the same server and database.

Comment: Please check if it has to do with Date/Region settings on each machine? Perhaps those influence how a connection is made or how queries are sent.

Comment: Also please state if the queries are run by everyone on the same server + same database or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define date literals as [ISO-8601](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms190977(v=sql.90))(culture independent):

> The advantage in using the ISO 8601 format is that it is an international standard. Also, datetime values that are specified by using this format are unambiguous. **Also, this format is not affected by the SET DATEFORMAT or SET LANGUAGE settings.**

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE col = 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss';
```

or:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE col = 'yyyymmdd';
```

Comment: Can I set the datetime data in a query to the ISO-8601 format and work with the dates that way? Some date columns I have to rework into an excel style text based date such as dd/mm/yyyy so I need to know the dates are all set in one format before I start converting and/or pulling them apart.

Comment: Date columns have no intrinsic format since the values are stored in an unreadable binary format. As lad2025 said - write your date literals using the suggested format. When you need to convert date columns/variables to strings, use the appropriate style parameter and specify the correct length for the char/varchar datatype you want. Need more info? Read [this](http://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes)